# Change the h1 of featured product.liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am working with a page that has multiple h1's, the reason is becuase feature products have a h1 in their title.

This is what's inside featured-product.liquid, the rest is schema

```
{%- if section.settings.divider -%}<div class="section--divider">{%- endif -%}

{%- assign product = all_products[section.settings.featured_product] -%}
{%- if product != blank -%}
{%- render 'product-template',
  product: product,
  section_id: section.id,
  blocks: section.blocks,

  image_position: section.settings.image_position,
  image_container_width: section.settings.image_size,
  product_zoom_enable: section.settings.product_zoom_enable,
  sku_enable: section.settings.sku_enable,
  thumbnail_position: section.settings.thumbnail_position,
  thumbnail_arrows: section.settings.thumbnail_arrows,
  mobile_layout: section.settings.mobile_layout,
  video_looping: section.settings.enable_video_looping,
  video_style: section.settings.product_video_style,
  is_recommendation: true
-%}
{%- endif -%}
```

It seems that I am simply telling the code what information to take, but how can I make that only in this area the title has a h2? I have been researching for hours on this topic, but I can't find much information.

I am working with the impulse template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside `featured-product.liquid` you see the code of:

```
{%- render 'product-template',
......
-%}
```

which is referring that you are including a snippet called `'product-template'` so on folder `snippets` you will find a file called `product-template.liquid`, open that file, and you will find the `<h1>` you can change it to `<h2>` if you want

---

if you want to keep `product-template.liquid` to keep using `<h1>`on some other places, then:

1. Duplicate this snippet `product-template.liquid` to make `new-product-template.liquid` and on the `new-product-template.liquid` change the `<h1>` to `<h2>`
2. Inside `featured-product.liquid` use the duplicated snippet `new-product-template.liquid` so it will be: `{%- render 'new-product-template', ..... -%}`